# Disable Tooltipster Tooltip on button click?

Tags: jquery, tooltip, tooltipster

I am using the Tooltipster tooltip on my website.

I want to know, is there a way to disable a Tooltipster tooltip that is showing, on a mouse button click ?

Like suppose I have a form and the Submit button has a Tooltipster tooltip on it which shows when the user hovers the mouse over the submit button. Now, I want the tooltip to be disabled immediately (i.e. go away) when the user clicks on that form Submit button. Can this be done somehow ?

Comment: removing tooltip or just disabling for the moment?

Comment: Either would work .. Ideal situation would be to just disable it for like 10 seconds or so ..

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me:

```
$('#idToHide').tooltipster('content', null);
```

Answer (score 0):

$('#idToHide').tooltipster('hide');